# How to update graphics driver

Tags: drivers, updates

I accidentally installed another display driver for my PC and while it was installing, it informed me that I had better drivers, the name of which I do not remember. Now the driver on my PC is a 2012 version of Intel (R) hd graphics. Whenever I try updating it from device manager, it always tells me that the best driver for my PC is already installed. So I tried updating from windows update and while doing so, i saw that a new display driver was amongst the list of new updates. But it failed to install. Pls is there anything I can do to update my driver bacause I can't play any high graphic games.

Comment: I normally download Intel drivers directly from Intel.

Comment: Better info if you tell us precisely *which* Intel HD & also your exact OS. Generally for older machines, you should get drivers directly from Intel, not Microsoft. https://downloadcenter.intel.com though support for Win10 is very limited & your card will probably not be fast enough & below minimum spec for modern games.

Comment: Intel (R) hd graphics version 8.15.10.2900

Comment: Which GPU & which OS, not which outdated driver set.

Comment: Depending on what graphics your system has 2012 might well be the latest drivers. Old systems get discontinued all the time.

Comment: Intel (R) HD Graphics (Core i3), windows 10 pro 2019 Microsoft Corporation. (Formerly windows 7)

Comment: Sounds like you have a first gen i3 maybe 10 years old - not fully supported on Win10. See my earlier link to check if it's one of the ones they made late chipset drivers for. There's an option to get Intel to scan your machine to get the correct drivers. You will probably be far below min spec for most modern games, even with latest drivers.